# Using count/mutate combo with purrr:map

Tags: r, purrr

Sample data:

```
       ï..Employee_Name       PositionID              Position State  Zip
  1:   Adinolfi, Wilson  K         19  Production Technician I    MA 1960
  2: Ait Sidi, Karthikeyan         27                  Sr. DBA    MA 2148
  3:     Akinkuolie, Sarah         20 Production Technician II    MA 1810
  4:          Alagbe,Trina         19  Production Technician I    MA 1886
  5:       Anderson, Carol         19  Production Technician I    MA 2169
 ---                                                                     
307:        Woodson, Jason         20 Production Technician II    MA 1810
308:     Ybarra, Catherine         19  Production Technician I    MA 2458
309:      Zamora, Jennifer          6                      CIO    MA 2067
310:           Zhou, Julia          9             Data Analyst    MA 2148
311:         Zima, Colleen         19  Production Technician I    MA 1730
```

I wrote my own fucntion that counts instances of observations for a variable in my dataframe and then converts them into factors:

```
HRdata_factor_count <- function(df, var) {
        df %>% 
        count(.data[[var]], sort = T) %>% 
        mutate(!!var := fct_reorder(factor(.data[[var]]), n))
    }
```

And I would like to use it with the map function in the Purrr package but I get the following error:

```
> map(HRdata, ~HRdata_factor_count(.x))
 Error in UseMethod("count") : 
  no applicable method for 'count' applied to an object of class "character"
```

How would I fix this issue and have map return a list with the counts of instances for each variable within my df?

I tried this but got a weird output

```
    HRnames <- names(HRdata)
map2(HRdata, HRnames, ~HRdata_factor_count, df = .x, var =.y)

$Position
function(df, var) {
  df %>% 
    count(.data[[var]], sort = T) %>% 
    mutate(!!var := fct_reorder(factor(.data[[var]]), n))
}
<bytecode: 0x000001e2ce372f60>

$State
function(df, var) {
  df %>% 
    count(.data[[var]], sort = T) %>% 
    mutate(!!var := fct_reorder(factor(.data[[var]]), n))
```

Comment: can you add some example data? Is `HRdata` a list? In addition you can transform within `count` like `mtcars %>% count(cyl = factor(cyl)) %>% glimpse()`

Comment: also check that your `HRdata_factor_count()` function specifies 2 input variables, `df` and `var`. In your `map()` call you only supply 1, i.e. `.x`

Comment: I have added sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According your provided data, you can try `purrr`'s `imap`

```
imap(mtcars, ~count(tibble(.x), !!.y := factor(.x)))
```

As function

```
foo <- function(x, y) count(tibble(x), !!y := factor(x))
imap(mtcars, foo)
```

- `.x` = each column as vector. check `map(mtcars, ~.)` or `imap(mtcars, ~.x)`
- `.y` = corresponding column name: `names(mtcars)`

Since `count` needs a data.frame or a tibble as input, one need to transform the input vectors again using `tibble(x)`. Factors are specified within `count`.

Edit:

Add the factor reorder like this:

```
foo <- function(x, y){ count(tibble(x), tmp = factor(x)) %>% 
                       mutate(!!y := fct_reorder(tmp, n, .fun = sum)) %>% 
                       select(-tmp)}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it with the function I created? I tried it using map2 and updated my inquiry above

Comment: no. your function will not wortk that way. See the comment from Ray my hint, that .x is an vector not a data.frame.

Comment: Hey you helped me out a lot by pointing me back to Ray's comment. I realised that I didn't need to use the function I wrote. In the end I just used a normal map with a table function on my dataframe and it worked fine. I'm still trying to figure out how to fct_reorder at the same time but I think it has something to do with piping.